# my CheckBox.isChecked() is always null

Tags: android

i'm currently making a MCQ for an application, and right now i'm making the button how must see if my answer is right or not !

I'm getting choice from related question by a multiMap and i'm getting Checkbox by an inflater like that :

```
for (String answer : multiMap.get(questionFromMultiMap))
        {
            CheckBox et_button = (CheckBox) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.numberofchoices, null);
            container.addView(et_button);
            et_button.setText(answer);
            listOfChoice.add(answer);

        }
```

And when i'm trying to check if one of them is check and get string, the logcat told me :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
     at lyceraymondpointcar.entinfo.Games.Symptom$1.onClick(Symptom.java:87)
```

Here is how i check if it's checked or not

```
btnCorrect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ((et_button).isChecked()){
                String choice = et_button.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("pouet");
            }else {
                //getQuestionAndAnswerFromList();
                System.out.println("pouet");


            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know why i'm getting this error, if someone can explain it to me.

To me, it's a problem with my inflator, because i have 3 or 4 checkbox with the same id ! So how can i do ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: try it using `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: given the scope of your code excerpts, it is not possible that `et_button` are the same variable. You are probable shadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into variable **scope**. You're probably declaring `et_button` at 2 places, and you're not giving value to the one you're accessing at this line:

```
if ((et_button).isChecked())
```

You need to remove `Checkbox` from this line like this:

```
et_button = (CheckBox) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.numberofchoices, null);
```

Because this way you are actually assigning value to the `et_button` you're accessing below.

**I'm assuming you have `et_button` declared elsewhere in your activity since the compiler is giving you a NPE, and not 'variable `et_button` not defined'.**

EDIT:
Also 1 pair of brackets are obsolete here so remove them like so:

```
if (et_button.isChecked())
```

Comment: Yes ! it's right ! I just remove Checkboxfrom the line and it worked ! thanks !

Comment: Other problem now, it only check if my last checkbox is checked :s
i'm trying to use setIt in my inflate right now

Comment: Good luck :D Glad to have helped. I hope you understand what you've done wrong? If not, write and I'll edit the answer with a short example.\

Comment: Yeah i understand what i've done wrong and that was really stupid because i already have use this method for a other game like that but i didn't let the "CheckBox" in that case :)

Comment: Good, then. Dont beat yourself up over stupid mistakes, we've all made them very many times, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.numberofchoices, null);
CheckBox et_button = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID);
            container.addView(et_button);
```

Comment: Just had to remove the Checkbox ! thanks for trying to helped me !

Answer (score 0):

do you have this `CheckBox et_button = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID);` correct?  "YOUR_CHECKBOX_ID" is correct?

Comment: Yeah i have it, the solution was given by Vucko

You need to remove Checkbox from this line like this:

et_button = (CheckBox) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.numberofchoices, null)

Thanks for trying to help me, really appreciate !